# How to change File content type for AWS s3 bucket before upload in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following code which allows me to successfully upload files to my S3 bucket.

```
$keyName = 'test_example/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
$pathInS3 = 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/' . $bucketName . '/' . $keyName;

// Add it to S3
try {

    $s3->putObject(
        array(
            'Bucket'=>$bucketName,
            'Key' =>  $keyName,
                        'contentType' => 'image/png',

            'SourceFile' => $keyName,
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
        )
    );

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Problem is that they download instead of showing the image. I have looked around a bit a tried adding: 'contentType' => 'image/png', which doesn't change anything. The file still uploads as Value application/octet-stream instead of Jpg image. Is there a way to change this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for some reason.

'contentType' => 'image/png',

did not work for me. Instead I've used

'ContentType' => 'text/plain',

And I can now view my images instead of it downloading.